# Radius of convergence for the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

> If the radius of convergence for the series
>   $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}$ is $R$, find the radius of convergence
>   of the following:
>
> a.) $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j^3a_jz^j$
>
> b.) $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a^4_jz^j$
>
> c.) $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{2j}$
>
> d.) $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j+7}$

My attempt:

For a I got $\frac{1}{R}$, but the answer is $R$, why is that? I got $\frac{1}{R}$ because since $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}$ is $R$ then $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j^3a_jz^j
=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j^3R$$ and $j^3$ will converge to $1$ thus why I got $\frac{1}{R}$ from the formula: $$
    R = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}} $$

Comment: Your problem may come from your careless attitude toward mathematical usage. It is not true that $\sum_0^{\infty}a_jz^j$ is $R$; what is true is that thr radius of convergence of that series in $R$. And what you mean by "$j^3$ will converge to $1$" is anybody's guess, when $j$ is going from zero to infinity. Anyway, let me suggest applying the ratio test on these problems.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I got $j^3$ to converge to one by ratio test and also from the formula $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$. And how will I be able to construct it "correctly" as you said. If $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}$ is $R$ and I know $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ goes to $1$ for $j^3$, what is the proper way of constructing it. My book is more theory based and doesn't go over much computation.

Comment: @Q.matin, in a book there is no space for a lot of computation, author expects the reader to do them on their own

Comment: $j^3$ does not converge to $1$. $j^3$ does not converge to $1$. $j^3$ does not converge to $1$. Something related in some precise way to $j^3$ does converge to $1$, but $j^3$ does not converge to $1$, and as long as you write stuff about $j^3$ converging to $1$, you have a snowball's chance in Hell of getting this stuff right. Similarly, $\sum a_jz^j$ isn't $R$; something related in a mathematically precise way to $\sum a_jz^j$ is $R$, but $\sum a_jz^j$ isn't $R$. In Mathematics, it is possible (and important!) to say exactly what we mean, and not sorta kinda something like what we mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I apologize, I will take your advice to heart now. I will restate it, tell me if this is better. If we apply the ratio test or from the formula $\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3}}$, to the coefficent of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}j^3a_jz^j$, we will see that the coefficent will converge to $1$?

Comment: You're still saying "the coefficient will converge to $1$", where "the coefficient" might mean $j^3$ or might mean $j^3a_j$, when in fact there is no coefficient converging to $1$. What is converging to $1$ is $(j+1)^3/j^3$, which is not $j^3$ and is not a coefficient of anything.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, but you neglect to mention that I also said it will converge to one by the ratio test. Which is implying that $(j+1)^3/j^3$ converges. But I will make it more explicit next time. I will take your advice, I know that I've been a headache to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) it is $R$ as we know that 
$$\sqrt[j]{|j^3 a_j|}=\sqrt[j]{|j^3|} \cdot \sqrt[j]{|a_j|}.$$
We know that $$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$$
and we have $$R_1 = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|n^3|} \cdot \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}=
\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^3}} \cdot \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}= 1\cdot R$$
For b) it is $R^4$ as 
$$\sqrt[j]{|a_j^4|}=(\sqrt[j]{|a_j|})^4$$
For c) you have 
$$\sqrt[2j]{|a_j|}=\sqrt{\sqrt[j]{|a_j|}}$$
And for d) recall that when $x_n$ is a convergent series the limits of $x_n$ and $x_{n+k}$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ ar the same.

Comment: That is what I am having trouble. Why is it $R$?

Comment: @Q.matin i edited do you unterstand now ?

Comment: Yes I do, much more clear now. I was setting it up backwards, dumb mistake on my part, its pretty late here maybe I need some rest.